# Using a NOT LIKE clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I currently have a SQL statement where I am trying to filter out certain account numbers. I want all account numbers less than 20000000, is there anyway to write it out using something like

`AND ACCT_NO NOT LIKE '2%'` which does not work

Or...should I just use something like this:

`AND ACCT_NO < '20000000'`

Here is the filter statement:

```
WHERE adm_date BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2013-04-30'
AND adm_src_desc != 'SCHEDULED ADMISSION'
AND pt_no < '20000000'
AND B_Adm_Source != 'SCHEDULED ADMISSION'
AND B_Pt_No < '20000000'
AND B_Dsch_Date IS NOT NULL
```

Should I also try something like
and `acct < 20000000` without the quotes?

Thank You

Comment: what is datatype of ACCT_NO?

Comment: How is ACCT_NO defined?  Int? varchar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I want all account numbers less than 20000000
```

Definitely:

```
ACCT_NO < 20000000
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem, will accept answer when the time limit expires.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn´t work because the first number MAY NOT be a 2. means: Acc No. 2XX (200-299, 20-29 and so on) would not show up.

```
AND ACCT_NO NOT LIKE '2%'
```

This would be the right way.

```
AND ACCT_NO < '20000000'
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using

```
AND PT_NO < 20000000
AND B_PT_NO < 20000000
```

This solved the problem.